# How to download ember canary version using bower

Tags: ember.js, bower

I want to use the query-params feature in Ember. However, to do this, I need to download the canary version of ember. I am using bower for package management. How do I update my bower.json file in order to donwload latest canary version of Ember. Relevant parts of my bower.json file look as below:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "sass-bootstrap": "~2.3.0",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.4",
    "modernizr": "~2.6.2",
    "jquery": "~1.9.1",
    "requirejs-text": "~2.0.7",
    "ember": "http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember.js",
    "ember-prod": "http://builds.emberjs.com/canary/ember.prod.js",
    "datatables": "~1.9.4",
    "lodash": "~1.3.1",
    "font-awesome": "~3.2.1",
    "moment": "~2.1.0",
    "d3": "~3.2.6",
    "ember-model": "~0.0.7",
    "jquery-ui": "~1.10.3",
    "typeahead.js": "~0.10.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": ">=1.8.0",
  }
}
```

However, "bower install ember" does not show me following:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for ember, please choose one:
1) ember#* which resolved to e-tag:8ee2c1ef5 and has ember-table-shim#0.2.0, nvwebapp as dependants
2) ember#~1.0 which resolved to 1.0.1 and has ember-model#0.0.11 as dependants
```

If I select the first resolution, and then go to app/bower_components/ember/index.js file, following can be seen at the top of the file:

```
/*!
 * @overview  Ember - JavaScript Application Framework
 * @copyright Copyright 2011-2014 Tilde Inc. and contributors
 *            Portions Copyright 2006-2011 Strobe Inc.
 *            Portions Copyright 2008-2011 Apple Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license   Licensed under MIT license
 *            See https://raw.github.com/emberjs/ember.js/master/LICENSE
 * @version   1.4.1+pre.af87bd20
 */
```

So, it seems that this is downloading version 1.4.1, however the latest canary version is 1.6.0.

How should I update my bower.json file to get the latest canary version?

Thanks in advance..!!

Comment: I also want to know this because of `query-params-new`. For now I'm using "ember": "1.4.0-beta.3" which still includes `query-params-new`. Later beta versions doesn't have it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Source: http://www.ember-cli.com/user-guide/#using-canary-build-instead-of-release

#### Using canary build instead of release

In `bower.json` instead of a version number use:

```
"ember": "components/ember#canary",
```

And, following dependencies add resolutions:

```
"resolutions": {
  "ember": "canary"
}
```

This can also be applied to Ember Data:

```
"ember-data": "components/ember-data#canary",
```

And, adding to resolutions:

```
"resolutions": {
  "ember-data": "canary"
}
```

Wipe your vendor directory clean then run `npm install && bower install`.

Comment: For Ember CLI read: http://www.ember-cli.com/#using-canary-build-instead-of-release

Comment: Jacob, Thanks for the link. Looks, it is getting more simpler. :)

Comment: @nikhil this answer is still relevant, if you agree, could you please accept as an answer? Cheers mate. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the canary build by specifying just the build number, like this -
"ember": "1.4.0-beta.2"

I am using beta.2 for query params.
You also need to explicitly enable this feature.

Comment: I believe your answer is on how to use beta versions, not canary, right?