# How to get the ember-data 1.0 beta version with bower?

Tags: ember-data, bower

I want to manage all the frontend components with bower.

When downloading ember with bower, i get the 1.5.1 version.

Afterwards when downloading the  ember-data i get:

> $ bower install ember-data bower cached
>   git://github.com/components/ember-data.git#0.0.14 bower validate
>   0.0.14 against git://github.com/components/ember-data.git#* bower cached        git://github.com/components/ember.git#1.0.1 bower
>   validate      1.0.1 against
>   git://github.com/components/ember.git#~1.0.0
>
> Unable to find a suitable version for ember, please choose one:
>       1) ember#~1.0.0 which resolved to 1.0.1 and is required by ember-data#0.0.14
>
> ```
> 2) ember#~1.5.1 which resolved to 1.5.1 and is required by davidga
> ```
>
> Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
>
> [?] Answer:

I want to use ember 1.0 beta as i know it from the getting started guide and it works fine with the 1.5.1 version of ember.

How do i tell bower to download the ember-data beta version?

I tried to fix it like the following post [How to download ember canary version using bower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444436/how-to-download-ember-canary-version-using-bower)

but it did not work.

> ```
> bower install ember-data:"1.0.0-beta.5"
> wer ENOTFOUND     Package ember-data:1.0.0-beta.5 not found
> ```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer according to this link

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/meet-bower-a-package-manager-for-the-web--net-27774

If i want a specific version i have to write # and then the version

> bower install ember-data#1.0.0-beta.8

Answer (score 0):

```
bower install ember-data-shim
```

this command will install ember-data 1.0.0-beta.8

in bower.json:
"ember-data-shim": "1.0.0-beta.8",

Comment: It did not work for me with the command line. It still tried to download the 0.14 version